# Converting Javascript Encryption Method to Java

Tags: java, javascript, encryption

So I found part of an encryption that I'm not advanced enough in to convert to java. This is the javascript encryption:

```
function rstr2binl(input) {
    var output = Array(input.length >> 2);
    for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
        output[i] = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < input.length * 8; i += 8)
        output[i>>5] |= (input.charCodeAt(i / 8) & 0xFF) << (i%32);

    return output;
}
```

I had trouble trying to figure out kind of data the output can be. Here was my attempt:

```
private static String rstr2binl(String input)
{
    tnt[] output = {input.length() >> 2};

    for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
        output[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length() * 8; i += 8)
        output[i>>5] |= (input.charAt(i / 8) & 0xFF) << (i%32);

    return output;
}
```

Would anybody be able to show me how to convert this javascript to java?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you declare the variable `output` as `int[]` the return type of the method should be `int[]` not `String`.

However, a quick search for this method indicates that it is part of a JavaScript library to generate MD5 Message Digests.

http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html

In which case I would suggest that the best way to implement it in Java is to not try to write your own cryptography functions and just use the standard Java libraries. The `java.security.MessageDigest` class can return an MD5 hash.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html